# SOLR Basic Authentication with SolrNet on 0.3.1

Tags: .net, solr, solrnet

I am trying to implement the basic auth with SOLRNet and I am using SolrNet 0.3.1 lib. 
I noticed a default basicauth in SolrNet 0.4.0, but do not see the same in 0.3.1.

My Question is in two folds?

1. How do I implement basic with Solrnet 0.3.1 ?
2. When does the NuGet releases 0.4.0 which has not updated from March
   2012, but the SolrNet 0.4 is relased officially.

Reference:
https://nuget.org/packages/SolrNet/0.3.1

Comment: I agree with Mauricio, I just implemented basic authentication with SolrNet 0.4.0 and it was super simple.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Do you guys have any info on the question # 2 (0.4.0 availability via NuGet)?